# Reading Multiple CSV files as data frames in R

Tags: r, csv

I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out, I have read so many blogs and tried different things but I still get the same error, and I don't understand what is wrong with my code.I am trying to pull several csv files into R all at once and I keep getting the following error.

> No such file or directoryError in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

```
`Tea_ONE <- "~/Desktop/Circadian Rhythms 
   Sem/Project/Tea_Party_ONE/Tea_Party_ONE_Lumicycle_data/"

      files <- list.files(path = Tea_ONE, pattern = ".csv$")

 for(i in 1:length(files)){
     assign(files[i],
     read.csv(paste(Tea_ONE, files[i], header = T, skip = 1)))
  }`
```

all of the CSV files are located in the Tea_Party_ONE_Lumicycle_data.

Thanks for any help

Comment: @RonakShah Note that the OP is pasting the full path together. The problem might actually be that the default paste() setting is adding a blank space to the path. Not the kention the passing read.csv arguments to paste() by mistake.

Comment: @joran Yep. I missed that. Thanks. You are right must be because of an extra space which is added by default in the `paste` argument. OP should try `paste0` instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are so many ways!!

```
setwd("C:/your_path_here")
fnames <- list.files()
csv <- lapply(fnames, read.csv)
result <- do.call(rbind, csv)


********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  


filedir <- setwd("C:/your_path_here")
file_names <- dir(filedir)
your_data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv))


********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  


filedir <- setwd("C:/your_path_here")
file_names <- dir(filedir)
your_data_frame <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names, read.csv, skip = 1, header = FALSE))


********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  


filedir <- setwd("C:/your_path_here")
file_names <- dir(filedir)
your_data_frame <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names, read.csv, header = FALSE))


********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ******** 


# 
temp <- setwd("C:/your_path_here")
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)


********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ******** 


# Here is another options to convert the .csv files into one data.frame. Using R base functions. 
# This is order of magnitude slower than the options below.

files <- setwd("C:/your_path_here")
# Get the files names
files = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
# First apply read.csv, then rbind
myfiles = do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))

library(readr)
library(dplyr)
tbl = lapply(files, read_csv) %>% bind_rows()


********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ******** 


# LIST OF FILE PATHS

library(readr)
library(stringr)

List_of_file_paths <- list.files(path ="C:/your_path_here/", pattern = ".csv", all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)


********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********


# LIST OF FILES IN FOLDER
xlist<-list.files(pattern = "*.csv")

for(i in xlist) { 
  x <- read.csv((i))
  assign(i, x)
    }


********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********
```

Answer (score 7):

As was mentioned in the comments, the problem is that `paste` is adding a space separator. You can use `paste0` or you can just get the full path names.

```
library('tidyverse')

files <- list.files(path = Tea_ONE, pattern = '.csv$', full.names = T) %>%
  map(read_csv, skip = 1)
```

Comment: The `full.names = TRUE` parameter is great - so you don't need to change your working directory!

Answer (score 2):

## purrr package to use map_dfr function

```
library(purrr)
```

## List all files ending with csv in directory

```
csv_files = list.files(path = 'data/folder/', pattern = "csv$", full.names = TRUE)
```

## Read csv files and place in dataframe

```
data_stacked <- map_dfr(csv_files, read_csv)
```